# How to block divs from taking any input at a specific point in the function

Tags: javascript

Got this code for a tic-tac-toe game and it's pretty much done.
https://jsfiddle.net/mnc5ytp6/

I got one issue I can't seem to find a solution.
Basically, it's all good until someone wins the game, after that if blocks for X and 0 were left unfilled, the player can still fill them and if it makes another 3X or 30, score goes up.

My question is:
How can I block the squares that are left unfilled in case a player wins early?

```
if(checkForWinner()){
        if(currentTurn === 2){ // X player wins
            alert(`${player1Name} won this round.`)
            player1score++
            document.querySelector('#player_one_score').innerText = player1score

        }
        else{
            alert(`${player2Name} won this round.`)
            player2score++
            document.querySelector('#player_two_score').innerText = player2score

        }
```

Comment: have you tried disabling the remaining divs?

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable `game_ended`. When the game starts it is `false`. When someone wins, it becomes `true`. If the `game_ended` variable is true when someones click on the cell, nothing happens. ;-)

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/sye2anhr/1/

When you reset the game, you also reset this variable back to `false` state.

```js
const positions = document.querySelectorAll('.col')
const winningCombo = [
    [0,1,2],
    [0,3,6],
    [0,4,8],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [2,4,6]
]

let player1 = 'X';
let player2 = '0';

let player1score = 0;
let player2score = 0;

let currentTurn =  1;
let movesMade = 0;

let game_ended = false;

const player1NameAsk = prompt("First player's name: ").split('')
player1Name = player1NameAsk[0].toUpperCase() + player1NameAsk.slice(1).join('')
const player2NameAsk = prompt("Second player's name: ").split('');
player2Name = player2NameAsk[0].toUpperCase() + player2NameAsk.slice(1).join('')

function setPlayersNames(){
    

    document.querySelector('#player_one').innerText = player1Name;
    document.querySelector('#player_two').innerText = player2Name;
    document.querySelector('#player_one_score').innerText = player1score;
    document.querySelector('#player_two_score').innerText = player2score;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setPlayersNames)
document.querySelector('#reset').addEventListener('click', resetScore)
document.querySelector('#game').addEventListener('click', resetGame)




positions.forEach((position) =>{
    position.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
        
        // If the game ended, ask the user if he wants another round
        if (game_ended){
          if(confirm('Game ended. Do you want to start another round?')){
            resetGame();
          }
          return;
        }
        
        movesMade++;
        
        if(currentTurn === 1){
            if(e.currentTarget.innerHTML === ''){
                e.currentTarget.style.color = 'red'
                e.currentTarget.innerHTML = player1;
                currentTurn += 1;
                e.currentTarget.style.background = 'rgba(172,172,172,0.5)';
                
                
            }      
        }else{
            if(e.currentTarget.innerHTML === ''){
                e.currentTarget.style.color = 'blue'
                e.currentTarget.innerHTML = player2;
                currentTurn -= 1;
                e.currentTarget.style.background = 'rgba(76,76,76,0.8)';
                
                     
            }           
        }
                
    if(checkForWinner()){
        if(currentTurn === 2){ // X player wins
            alert(`${player1Name} won this round.`)
            player1score++
            document.querySelector('#player_one_score').innerText = player1score
            game_ended = true;
        }
        else{
            alert(`${player2Name} won this round.`)
            player2score++
            document.querySelector('#player_two_score').innerText = player2score
            game_ended = true;
            
        }
    }

    })

    function checkForWinner(){
        if(movesMade > 4){
            let moves = Array.prototype.slice.call(positions);
            let results = moves.map((e)=>{
                return e.innerHTML})
        
        
            return winningCombo.find((combo) =>{
                if (results[combo[0]] !== "" && results[combo[1]] !== "" && results[combo[2]] !== "" && results[combo[0]] === results[combo[1]] && results[combo[1]] === results[combo[2]]) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            })
        }      
    }
})



function resetGame() {
  
    game_ended = false;
    currentTurn = 1;
    
    positions.forEach((e) =>{
        e.innerHTML = ''
        e.style.background = 'white'
    })
}
    


function resetScore(){
    player1score = 0;
    player2score = 0;
    document.querySelector('#player_one_score').innerText = player1score;
    document.querySelector('#player_two_score').innerText = player2score;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 30%;
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.row{
    width: 150px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.col{
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    font-size: 4rem;
}
  

td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#blank,
#reset_button,
#reset_game{
    border:none;
}

#player_one,
#player_one_score,
#player_two_score,
#player_two,
#reset_button,
#reset_game{
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id='blank'></td>
                <td id="player_one"></td>
                <td id='player_two'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Score</td>
                <td id='player_one_score'></td>
                <td id='player_two_score'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id='reset_button'><button id='reset'>Reset Score</button></td>
                <td id='reset_game'><button id='game'>Reset Game</button></td>
            </tr>


        </table>


    </div>
    

    <script src='config.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the click events in that particular div by using pointer-events property.

For eg. You can do something like

***document.getElementById("div").style.pointerEvents = "none";***

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can remove click handler. In your code above the mentioned one, you have `position.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{})`. Extract that arrow func to a normal named function, e.g. `clickHandler(){}`. Then, if you have a winner (means 'end of game'), for all positions do `position.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)`. 
On a new game, you can re-setup click handlers.
Here's docs for it. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener